# Ruby on Rails "What's new?"-modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently developing a webapp using Rails and lately the system has become too large for users ti realize what has changed after I deploy an update. I would like to implement some sort of "What's new?" modal to show up after a new deploy has been made. Does anyone know of a good existing gem for this or will  have to make it from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

My approach to this is to have a "News"-model, for storing `title` and `content`, and then storing the "last login" date for a User.
So whenever they log in, I check to see if there's been a news since last login - If there has been any - I'll show it to them on the next page after login.

Comment: Thanks! I had something similar in mind if I were to do it manually. Just wanted to check if anyone knew of an existing service for it.

Comment: Probably exists somewhere - I just thought it easier to do it myself, since i already logged `last_login` as a datetime.. Just compare it with `News.where('created_at > ?', @user.last_login)` or something along those lines.